# Conditional replace using regex

Tags: regex, c++11

I need some help with formatting strings using regex. I have a string of type

> (33,2),(44,2),(0,11)

I have to reformat this string to the following

> (2),(2),(0,11)

That is, remove `(\\([[:digit:]]+\\,)` from the input except for the last occurrence.

I tried the following code, but it replaces all occurrences.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main ()
{
  std::string s ("(32,33),(63,22),(22,1)");
  std::regex e ("[[:digit:]]+\\,"); 
  std::string result;

  std::regex_replace (std::back_inserter(result), s.begin(), s.end(), e, "$2");
  std::cout << result;

  return 0;
}
```

I understand that I need to use `std::sregex_iterator` to get this done but haven't been able to figure this out.

Appreciate all help.

Comment: do u want this? https://regex101.com/r/poo4t4/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match these digits only if they are followed with `(`:

```
[[:d:]]+,(?=.*\()
```

**Details**:

- `[[:d:]]+` - 1 or more digits
- `,` - a comma
- `(?=.*\\()` - a positive lookahead requiring a `(` after any 0+ chars other than linebreak chars.

The positive lookahead here can be replaced with a negtive `(?![[:d:]]+\\)$)` lookahead to fail all matches of the digits+`,` if they are followed with 1+ digits + `)` at the end of the string.

See [C++ demo](http://ideone.com/ZSccEx):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main ()
{
  std::string s ("(32,33),(63,22),(22,1)");
  std::regex e ("[[:d:]]+,(?=.*\\()"); 
  std::string result;

  std::regex_replace (std::back_inserter(result), s.begin(), s.end(), e, "$2");
  std::cout << result;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked perfectly. I didn't think of  using "(?=.*\\()" as a condition to check. Newbie issues.. :)